# Why is my JS SPA app not loading from the services URL (404)? OR Why is there a space in my generated URL containing a username? (on certain browsers)

Tags: c#, javascript, iis, backbone.js, asp.net-web-api

OK - This is a complex one and I'm not sure where to start looking at it.

I have a Backbone JS based site and an ASP.Net Web API based service layer which has been deployed onto the live server. The problem I have is that on certain platforms some of the services don't work.

Architecturally, the BackboneJS app runs off a single Razor script in a .net project. The API itself is in a separate project running in the '/api' subdirectory.

I have tested the app on the following platforms. I can log in on all of them, so the user login services (which just provide very simple key data back from input) are obviously working fine, however whenever I try and load any data for any of the other screens in the app it fails. Here's the test results...

- WINDOWS (IE 10) - Works fine
- WINDOWS (Firefox) - Works fine
- WINDOWS (Chrome) - Works fine
- OS X (Safari) - Fails to load any service data except for login
- OS X (Chrome) - Fails to load any service data except for login
- OS X (Firefox) - Works fine
- iOS (Safari) - Works fine
- iOS (Chrome) - Fails to load any service data except for login
- Android (Kit Kat) (Chrome) - Fails to load any service data except for login

My Backbone data load methods are coded to provide me with an error in the console if possible, which has proven interesting. If I look at the console in Chrome on the mac I can see this error...

```
Fetch Meal Plans failed: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The resource cannot be found.</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <style>
         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top:-5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

            <span><H1>Server Error in '/api' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>The resource cannot be found.</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
            <br><br>

            <b> Requested URL: </b>/api/mealplans/owner/username /<br><br>

    </body>
</html>
```

...this looks to be a fairly standard 404 error yet I can't figure out why this works on some browser / platform combinations and not others unless there's been some recent browser security change that may have impacted my app setup.

I can't reproduce the issue on my local machine at the moment (possibly because my dev machine is Windows and that just seems to work anyways /sigh). The server is https so I can't interrogate the traffic directly.

I'll add more info to this as I get it - The live server isn't in use yet so I may try disabling HTTPS so I can see what's going on.

Comment: I've just noticed something here that may explain this - The URL above shows a space after the username. That looks wrong. I shall report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this - The affected platforms were autocompleting the username and adding a space to the end of it for some reason.

This value is then being stored to represent the user query portion of the URL generated which results in an invalid URL. I'll update the title of this to make it a bit more searchable too as this is one of those things you can go round in circles with for ages.

So - The fix will be to trim the username field input before doing anything else with it to mitigate this issue.